# PayPal client-side express checkout using rest is not working in ios web application

Tags: javascript, cordova, jquery-mobile, paypal, checkout

I'm integrating PayPal client-side express checkout using REST.

here is code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

    <script>
        paypal.Button.render({

            env: 'sandbox', // sandbox | production

            // PayPal Client IDs - replace with your own
            // Create a PayPal app: https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/create
            client: {
                sandbox:    'AZDxjDScFpQtjWTOUtWKbyN_bDt4OgqaF4eYXlewfBP4-8aqX3PiV8e1GWU6liB2CUXlkA59kJXE7M6R',
                production: '<insert production client id>'
            },

            // Show the buyer a 'Pay Now' button in the checkout flow
            commit: true,

            // payment() is called when the button is clicked
            payment: function(data, actions) {

                // Make a call to the REST api to create the payment
                return actions.payment.create({
                    payment: {
                        transactions: [
                            {
                                amount: { total: '0.01', currency: 'USD' }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                });
            },

            // onAuthorize() is called when the buyer approves the payment
            onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {

                // Make a call to the REST api to execute the payment
                return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
                    window.alert('Payment Complete!');
                });
            }

        }, '#paypal-button-container');

    </script>
</body>
```

this code is working android mobile web application, but when i put this code in ios mobile web application PayPal checkout button is not showing in my html page.

Thanks, Kaushik.

Comment: Check this issue: [https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout/issues/433](https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout/issues/433)

Comment: @Frix33 Still issue fixed or not, Where is solution..?

Comment: @Frix33 Can you please help me..?

Comment: Issue is reopened here [https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout/issues/635](https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout/issues/635), but actually is still opened.

Comment: ok Thank you @Frix33 for answer.